# JSP page not rendering in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-boot

I have started on spring boot and tried to create this basic program 
but it is giving white error page:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Mar 21 23:06:15 IST 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

here is dependencies section of pom.xml file

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

index.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        Hello User....
    </body>
</html>
```

Application.properties file :

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

following is the controller class:

```
package com.whiteboard.banking;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }

}
```

I have tried to log message in index method and it is giving logging, which means this method is called but index.jsp is not rendering.

Can someone tell me reason of error?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spring Boot serves static content from a directory called /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources). you can override these by either implementing `WebMvcConfigurer` or extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and then override `addResourceHandlers`.

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
         .addResourceLocations(new String[] {"classpath:/", "classpath:/public/"}); 
  }
}
```

Maybe this can help you [spring static content](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)

Comment: my same code is working in someone else's machine. exactly same code I send to my friend, he just import maven project, build and run and it was working fine. what could be the possible reason ?

Comment: first `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` is depricated, there is no method by name of `addResourceLocations` with string param

Comment: @Sarvesh updated the answer. it's deprecated in the spring version 5.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to lucid answer, I want to precise/remind:

You should convert your project packaging to an executable war so that spring can locate your *.jsp

Please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47581352/spring-boot-with-tiles-static-webresources-not-found-when-deploying-as-jar/47583950#47583950). Hope was helpful :)

Comment: my same code is working in someone else's machine. exactly same code I send to my friend, he just import maven project, build and run and it was working fine. what could be the possible reason ?